# How to find an entity by a many to many related entity with Doctrine QueryBuilder or EntityManager

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities: Store and User.  They have a many to many relationship through a StoreUser join table. To be clear, nothing is stored in the join table other then the relationship data.

I have created both Store and User entities and set up all the relationship meta data in those entities.

I am now trying to figure out the simplest way to do a search for all Stores assigned to a specific User.  In my Store repository I have a `findAllByUser(User $user)` where I am trying to build a query to return a list of Stores based on the passed in User.

What is the easiest way to get the following type of query written:

SELECT * FROM `store`
JOIN `store_user` ON `store_user`.`store_id` = `store`.`id` 
WHERE `store_user`.`user_id` = 100001;

I should mention, I am trying to avoid needing to create an entity for StoreUser if at all possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it with DQL:

```
$query = $this  ->getEntityManager()
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('s')
                ->from('AcmeAcmeBundle:Store', 's')
                ->leftJoin('AcmeAcmeBundle:StoreUser', 'su', 'WITH', 'su.store_id = s.user_id')
                ->where('su.user_id = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', 100001)
                ->getQuery();

    $result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Will this work if I didnt generate the StoreUser entity?